# What does Design Voltage parameter mean

Tags: wmi

There is a parameter called "Design Voltage" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-battery

Can anybody tell me is that parameter from battery voltage sensor? I wonder how accurate that parameter. Or it's just approx.? Thanks!

Comment: There's information about that value about halfway down the page you link. Search that page for *DesignVoltage*.

Comment: Could you please drop that link

Comment: What link? It's the exact link you posted, about halfway down the page.

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, I didn't find any info over there.